# Objective-c: Count a NSDictionary but got wrong result

Tags: objective-c, ios

While implement the code below, I got `itemCount = 3`, but it should be `itemCount = 1` because I point to `Banner` > `Banner`. Did anyone know why I got this result and any fix for it?

Thanks

```
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:contents error:&parseError];

NSLog(@"xmlDictionary = %@", xmlDictionary);

int itemCount = [[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"Banner"] objectForKey:@"Banner"] count];

NSLog(@"itemCount = %d", itemCount);
```

LOG:

```
2012-03-02 12:54:49.728 BROADWAY[541:ef03] xmlDictionary = {
    Banner =     {
        Banner =         {
            date =             {
                text = "\n        29/02/2012";
            };
            name =             {
                text = "\n    \n        iPhone_Banner_HSB.jpg";
            };
            text = "\n    ";
        };
        text = "\n";
    };
}
2012-03-02 12:54:49.728 BROADWAY[541:ef03] itemCount = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count of a dictionary is the number of keys in the dictionary.

The top-level dictionary has one key: `Banner`.

That key's value is a dictionary with two keys: `Banner` and `text`.

The second `Banner` key's value is a dictionary with three keys: `date`, `name`, and `text`.  This is the dictionary that you counted.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dictionary of dictionaries.  The outer dictionary has one key "Banner" with the value being the inner Dictionary.

The inner Dictionary has 3 keys (date, name and text).

This line retrieve the inner dictionary (which has 3 values):

```
//   outer                                 inner                   count
[[[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"Banner"] objectForKey:@"Banner"] count];
```

Answer (score 0):

your dictionary has keys: "date","name","text".

That's three.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix..

in XMLReader.m, goto this method:

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

```
    //comment this line below 
    //[dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];

    //add the fix code
    /*FIX*/
    NSString * trimmedString = [textInProgress stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n"]];

    trimmedString=[trimmedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    /*FIX*/
```

}